# Los datos del formulario no son insertados a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios

Ya hice algunas cosas a mi codigo y ahora no me da error ni nada. Es más, ahora dice que se ha enviado con exito, pero al revisar mi base de datos veo que no se ha guardado nada.

```php
<?php
//Conexión con la base de datos y el servidor
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","Jonnathan","Angumba2005","proyecto2") or die("<h2>No se pudo conectar con la base de datos</h2>");
//Obtención de los datos con el metodo POST
$Cedula = $_POST["txtcedula"];
$Nombre = $_POST["txtnombre"];
$Direccion = $_POST["txtdireccion"];
$Telefono = $_POST["txttel"];
$Correo = $_POST["txtemail"];
$Genero = $_POST["lstgenero"];
echo "<div align=center>";
echo "La Cedula ingresada fue: ".$Cedula;
echo "<br>";
echo "El Nombre ingresado fue: ".$Nombre;
echo "<br>";
echo "La Direccion ingresads fue: ".$Direccion;
echo "<br>";
echo "El Telefono ingresado fue: ".$Telefono;
echo "<br>";
echo "El Correo ingresado fue: ".$Correo;
echo "<br>";
echo "El Genero seleccionado fue: ".$Genero;
echo "</div>";
//Ingreso de la información a la base de datos
$respuesta =mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO cedula VALUES ('Cedula','Nombre','Direccion','Telefono','Correo','cod_enero')" or die("<h2>Error en el envio de datos</h2>"));

echo("
<div align=center>
<h2>Envio de datos correcto</h2>
<h5>Gracias por enviar su formulario</h2>
</div>
");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás depurando correctamente las peticiones `mysqli` y quizás por eso no ves los errores que estan sucediendo.

Si te muestra que el formulario ha sido enviado es porque no se ha parado en los **OR DIE**, quizás porque no tenga errores, pero quizás sí los tiene y no se detiene por un tema de prioridades (el `=` tiene prioridad sobre el `or` en PHP, y segun parece si no devuelve un valor booleano no entra en el `or`).

Una forma de filtrar mejor estas funciones `mysqli` sería mediante el uso de la función `mysqli_report` antes de llamar a las funciones.

Por lo tanto agrega esto al principio del script en una línea:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Y luego quita todos los `or die` que tengas, dejándolos así:

```php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","Jonnathan","Angumba2005","proyecto2");
```

y así:

```php
$respuesta =mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO cedula VALUES ('Cedula','Nombre','Direccion','Telefono','Correo','cod_enero')");
```

y vuelve a probar si esta vez te salen errores en el script relacionados con las instrucciones `mysqli`.

Si aparecen corrígelos y tu script funcionará bien.

Otra forma de tratar los errores de las instrucciones mysqli seria mediante la captura de excepciones usando el bloque **try / catch** de este modo:

```php
try {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","Jonnathan","Angumba2005","proyecto2");
    $respuesta = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO cedula VALUES ('Cedula','Nombre','Direccion','Telefono','Correo','cod_enero')");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción/Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Este tipo de bloque intenta (**try**) ejecutar las instrucciones de primera parte del mismo (las consultas `mysqli`) y si alguna da algun error se genera una *excepción* y se captura el error producido, el cual se envia al bloque `catch` y es recogido mediante un objeto de clase Exception denominado `$e` en este caso (puede tener el nombre que quieras). Y a continuación se ejecutan las instrucciones del bloque `catch` que contenga. En este caso seria mostrar en la salida la cadena **"Excepción/Error:"** seguida del error reportado y capturado en la primera parte del bloque `try`.

Dicho de otro modo, es como lo que pretendes con `or die()` pero más versátil y más usado actualmente para gestionar esos errores.

Otro problema que tienes, y que quizas por eso no te aparecen nuevos registros, es que estás insertando siempre valores fijos, no los contenidos en las variables.

Fíjate que pones esto en la consulta del INSERT:

```
VALUES ('Cedula','Nombre','Direccion','Telefono','Correo','cod_enero')
```

Lo cual está mal, pues no son variables como tu crees, sino cadenas de texto puras. Por lo tanto siempre repites la misma inserción de los mismos datos, sin tener en cuenta los datos recibidos por $_POST.

Para que se usen las variables, que sí contienen eso datos, debes ponerlo así:

```
VALUES ('$Cedula','$Nombre','$Direccion','$Telefono','$Correo','$Genero')
```

Fíjate que he cambiado el valor `cod_enero` por la variable `$Genero` pues aparentemente alli tenias algún tipo de error tipográfico (realmente no lo se porque no has puesto la estructura de tu tabla en la pregunta).

Otro tema a tratar sería si esa es la mejor forma, pues no estás usando sentencias `prepare` que escaparian esos datos y evitarian posibles problemas de inyección por SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado sus consejos me han ayudado